# VBA Pass arguments with .onAction

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-2010

this is how my sub looks like:

```
Sub InsertRowWithContent(rowNo As Long)
```

This is my .onAction:

```
.OnAction = "'InsertRowWithContent""" & C & """'"
```

C is a *Long* variable declared earlier.

It says macro not found. It worked fine before adding an argument!

Comment: I should have asked first. The background of my answer is Access. Djikay answers you from Excel point of view. The tag in your question is Word. So these applications may significantly differ in those details. Which application do you use, and which version? - And another test: can you call `InsertRowWithContent(123)` from the "immediate window"? Maybe it's in a range not visible (e.g. other sheet/doc and private).

Comment: I'm using word 2010. What do you mean by calling it from the immediate window?

Comment: I'm calling it from the same module if that's what you mean. I have a button in a word document which when clicked displays a popup menu which is populated by items from an excel sheet. When one of these menu items is clicked,  i.e. when their .onAction is activated, they're supposed to call the insertRowWithContent method while passing an argument corresponding to the item number.

Comment: I've found a solution that seems robust. Have a look again. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have sucessfully passed arguments with this syntax:

```
.OnAction = "=InsertRowWithContent(" & C & ")"
```

Considerations:

- C is a long. So don't add quotas, just as you wouldn't if you would call the Sub in the code.
- OnAction evaluates an expression. Therefore according to my experience, the expression needs an equal sign, and as far as I now, it must be a function. Only automated local callbacks are subs.

**EDIT**

My answer above has Access as background. Djikay's answer works fine with Excel. Yet after some digging, I am quiet sure that simply Word doesn't understand either of those syntaxes. Word VBA cannot pass a parameter to a sub in an `OnAction` statement. At least for the moment it's best to accept this.

But here is what definitively runs with Word (2010):

Create your command bar and the button. For the `OnAction`, only pass the name of the `Sub`. But use the button's `Parameter` property.

```
' Add bar
Set cdb = Application.CommandBars.Add("SomeTest", , False, False)
cdb.Visible = True

' Add button
Set cbb = cdb.Controls.Add
cbb.Caption = "PressMe"
cbb.OnAction = "TheCallback"
cbb.Parameter = 456
```

Then, access the parameter by the `CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter` expression:

```
Public Sub TheCallback()

  MsgBox "The parameter passed is: " & CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter

End Sub
```

`ActionControl` is very similar (if not the same) as `ActiveControl` under Access: it is the control that was clicked last.

Source: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Visual_Basic/Q_24982922.html

*phuu* :-)

Comment: I don't get it. There's gotta by something else wrong with my project. It doesn't work either.

Comment: Seems like this will actually work. Unfortunately I'm not near my PC now but will try it in 30 minutes or so when I get back. I had actually read about this parameter property but I didn't figure that you had to access it exclusively, I thought it was just an alternative to putting the argument between parentheses.

Comment: dude you are the maaaaaaaaaaaaaaan!! I've been at this for hours!!

I owe you one brother!

Comment: Glad to help :-) ...I was also surprised what a maze this event handling is, compared over several Office programs. Good luck...

Answer (score 10):

You need to add a space after your Sub name, like this:

```
.OnAction = "'InsertRowWithContent " & C & "'"
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

**EDIT**

Also, since you're passing a Long parameter, you shouldn't enclose it in quotes.

**EDIT 2**

OK, this will require some special sauce (code). I've been experimenting and I got the following to work.

In the Sheet1 Excel object:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DestroyToolbar()

  Application.CommandBars("DoomBar").Delete

End Sub

Sub MakeToolbar()

  Dim C As Long
  C = 100

  With Application
    .CommandBars.Add(Name:="DoomBar").Visible = True
    With .CommandBars("DoomBar")
      .Controls.Add Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=2950, Before:=1
      With .Controls(1)
        .OnAction = "'PressMe " & C & "'"
      End With
    End With
  End With

End Sub
```

In a new standard code module, add this:

```
Public Sub PressMe(C As Long)

  With Application.CommandBars("DoomBar")
    With .Controls(1)
      MsgBox "The value of C that was passed to this macro is: " & C
    End With
  End With

End Sub
```

If you run `MakeToolbar`, it will create a new toolbar in the "Add-ins" ribbon. To remove it, you can run `DestroyToolbar`.

Once the toolbar is in place, then clicking the button should display a messagebox with the value of `C` (in my example, 100).

I've tested the above in Excel 2010 and it worked, in a brand new .xlsm file.

Comment: Didn't work. I think I tried that one before actually.

Comment: @Mohamed: I've added another update with full code this time.

Comment: Well, your code works when I copy it into a new xlsm file, but when I try to use the .onAction line it still gives me a "macro not found error". Possibly there is another problem apart from the code? Both the subs (the one setting the .onAction and the one called by .onAction) are in a standard module.

Comment: I didn't take too much risk of adding a toolbar.. but the SPACE thing in first line saved me... Thanks man!!