# Control Button OnAction macro running twice

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue that somehow is solved but I don't understand:

I am using control buttons on VBA excel such as:

```
With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    .Caption = "My caption"
    .OnAction = "TestMacro(5)"
End With
```

`5` is an input for the `testMacro` When I clicked on the button, the macro was running twice.

I solved the issue by now using `.OnAction = "'TestMacro 5'"`

I could see several posts for instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097756/vba-pass-arguments-with-onaction) where using a syntax with brackets is also a solution (also we can see that the other solution with single quote is also in the list of proposals, not main answer)

Why is it running twice ? which syntax is the correct one?

Comment: It's running twice because of the brackets. Technically there is no *correct* syntax, as this is not officially supported. Note that you are likely to have issues if you use this in a .xlsb format file.

Comment: @Rory, regarding running twice: then why does the brackets leads to run twice the same macro? Is there a case when running twice is intended or is it just an issue with the building of the function?
Regarding the function being not supported: This means there are functions which are available but not supported, do you know how to verify if the function I am concerned about is supported or not?

Comment: I don't know *why* it does that. I don't think anyone does. You'll see the same thing if you use that syntax with `Application.Run`. If you can't find any MS documentation of it, it's probably not supported.

Comment: ok thank-you, for your time and answers!

Comment: Maybe because you pass a string instead of a number. Try .OnAction = "TestMacro(" & CInt(5) & ")".

Comment: @BitAccesser Your Integer will immediately cast into a string if you append it with an `&` and is exactly the same as `.OnAction = "TestMacro(5)"`.

Comment: @BitAccesser, to support the note from Peh: the macro indeed still behave identically and run twice with the proposed syntax.

Comment: I agree, concat strings and numbers result in a string. If Jonathan shows the `TestMakro` code, I will ty to replicate, maybe I stumble over sth.

Comment: @BitAccesser it does not matter the macro either, you can try it as simple as this: `Sub TestMakro(MSr As Long) / MsgBox ("Test") / End Sub` it will run two times...

Comment: When VBA meets round brackets, it thinks the code contains some mathematical calculation so tries to evaluate or calculate  the code first( which causes the first run) and then finally run the returned command string(which is the second run), I assume.