# "Worksheet.activate" with "CommandBarControl.onaction" doesn't working

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dynamic rightclick menu, that I use to switch between the sheets, and select the necessary lines. My problem is that when the program starts run the macro with the ".onaction" method, the Worksheets("xy") does not prevail.

This is an example without any completeness:

```
[...]
Dim ws As Worksheet, i as long
i=0
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Menu1.Controls.add (msoControlButton)
    Menu1.Controls(i).Caption = ws.Name
    Menu1.Controls(i).OnAction = "SheetChange(""" & ws.Name & """)"
    i=i+1
Next

[...]

Sub SheetChange(x as string)
        worksheets(x).activate
        worksheets(x).Range("A1").select
end sub
```

Is there any way to use "activate" and "select" methods inside a sub, which called with ".onaction"?

Comment: See if [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25097883/1188513)

Comment: The action is working, can pass parameters as a string. The SheetChange is run correctly (i can do anything on that Sub, but it dosesn't select or change anything, until the Sub ended.

Comment: Is `ActiveWorkbook` the workbook you mean to work with, and does it change between the moment you setup your menu buttons and the moment you click them?

Comment: Seems your setup loop would create 20 identical buttons given an active workbook with 20 sheets - all buttons wired up to the same sheet. `.Caption = ws.Name`, `.OnAction = "SheetChange(""" & ws.Name & """)"`.

Comment: Yep, my bad, I edited, but it the activating with the menu still not working

Comment: If your workbook is waiting for the `Sub` to complete before continuing, you can try splitting the `Sub` into 2 parts and using `Application.OnTime Now(),"SecondPartOfSub"` to run the second part as soon as the first has finished & activated the worksheet.

Comment: Given that `i` coming out of nowhere, it's impossible that the code you've specified works anywhere near as claimed. Please read [mcve] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Edited again. It is an example code, what is wrote quickly, with lot of bug.

I want make a menu, to find references between two or more sheets' datas, and make a menubutton, when something intresting found. I can created a menu, with few button, and when I choose what I need, I would like to activate the correct sheet, with the selected rows. But sadly this is not working, becouse inside the "on action" command, the workbook doesn't change. If i call the Sub directly, its works perfectly. :(

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your actual code for creating the menu. Rubbish example code won't help anyone find what the problem is. Have you tried putting a breakpoint in your `SheetChange` procedure (F9), and validating the contents of `x` and whether the correct workbook was currently active?

Comment: The breakpoint is not working, when I click on the button. If I call directly the procedures, its work perfectly, and when I call it with the ControlButton, its call fine the SheetChange. But if I start with from the menu, it can't change sheet until the end of the procedurre what I call with a button ".onaction". My English is so bad, sorry, but the problem is not in this code example. I don't know, why I don't know debugging the subs after i call it with an msoControlButton, and why  not change sheet a procedure if i call with as an ".onaction" when its works, as call directly... :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "("...")"
try:

```
Menu1.Controls(i).OnAction = "'SheetChange """ & ws.Name & """'"
```