# OnAction with parameters

Tags: vba, ms-word, cross-reference

This is my first ever question on SO even I come here regularly (I've always find my answer without having to ask until today). I know this question I've already posted but for some reason i doesn't work for me.

I'm trying to get a right click submenu with a list of every numbered items in my word document. The purpose of it is to insert in a click the numbered and the content text of my numbered item in my document.

The problem is I don't know how to affect each .OnAction (to insert the numbered item in my document) and each .Caption (to show the number and content text of my numbered item in my menu) with a different variable (one for each numbered item). There is probably a problem with my quotes but I cannot see any other solution.

My code is the following :

```
Option Explicit

Sub ControlButtonNumberedItems()

'Parameters for NumberedItems
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Dim NumberedItems As Integer
NumberedItems = ActiveDocument.CountNumberedItems

'Parameters for CommanBar
Dim MenuButton As CommandBar
Set MenuButton = Application.CommandBars("Text")
Dim SubMenuButton As CommandBarControl
Set SubMenuButton = MenuButton.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, Before:=1)

With SubMenuButton
    .Caption = "NumberedItems"
    .Tag = "My_Tag"

    While i <= NumberedItems
        With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
            .OnAction = "'InsertNumberedItem""i""'"
            .FaceId = 38
            .Caption = "MyCaption"
        End With
        i = i + 1
    Wend

End With

End Sub

Sub InsertEvidence(i As Integer)

'Insert NumberRelativeContext
Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:=wdRefTypeNumberedItem, _
ReferenceKind:=wdNumberRelativeContext, _
ReferenceItem:=i, _
InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
SeparatorString:=" "

Selection.TypeText Text:=" "

'Insert ContentText
Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:=wdRefTypeNumberedItem, _
ReferenceKind:=wdContentText, _
ReferenceItem:=i, _
InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
SeparatorString:=" "

'Text form
Selection.Expand Unit:=wdLine
Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
Selection.Font.Italic = wdToggle
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
Selection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 6

End Sub

Sub ResetRightClick()
Application.CommandBars("Text").Reset 
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any help. Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079727/excel-vba-how-to-pass-multiple-variables-to-onaction   `.OnAction = "'InsertNumberedItem " & i & "'"`

Comment: Thank you Tim ! 

However, if this is the correct syntax, it seems there is an another problem in my macro, because I get this error message: "La macro est introuvable ou a été désactivée en raison de vos paramètres de sécurité des macros" ("The macro is not found or has been disabled due to your macro security settings" in English). 

The strange thing is that my macro works perfectly if I don't insert any parameters in my .OnAction. 

Any idea where it comes from?

Comment: Are you sure you're leaving a space after the macro name and before the argument?

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is still there.... I still get the same error message over and over. Does this macro work with you? Could it be a problem with my Word version (I have Word office 365Proplus)? Thanks for your help.
PS: the name of the Sub indicated in the".onaction" (InsertNumberedItem) did not match the name in my code (InsertEvidence), I've already fixed this error.

Comment: I can’t test this for a couple of days - no PC access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that Word VBA is different from Excel: see the accepted answer here:

[VBA Pass arguments with .onAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097756/vba-pass-arguments-with-onaction)

This worked for me (just the code needed to show how parameters can be passed):

```
Sub ControlButtonNumberedItems()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim NumberedItems As Integer

    'Parameters for CommanBar
    Dim MenuButton As CommandBar
    Set MenuButton = Application.CommandBars("Text")
    Dim SubMenuButton As CommandBarControl
    Set SubMenuButton = MenuButton.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, Before:=1)

    With SubMenuButton
        .Caption = "NumberedItems"
        .Tag = "My_Tag"

        For i = 1 To 5
            With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
                .OnAction = "InsertNumberedItem"
                .FaceId = 38
                .Parameter = i
                .Caption = "MyCaption " & i
            End With
        Next i

    End With

End Sub

Public Sub InsertNumberedItem()
    MsgBox "got " & CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter
End Sub

Sub ResetRightClick()
    Application.CommandBars("Text").Reset
End Sub
```

Comment: I was quite busy recently I couldn't respond earlier. Thanks a lot for your answer! I had to make some changes to your code but it works perfectly now, passing through Parameters.