# How to find control button that was clicked inside submenu

Tags: excel, vba, commandbar

I have menu with submenu made of control buttons:

```
Set MenuItem = .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
With MenuItem
    .caption = "Code Type"

    With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        .caption = "Lists"
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "setCaption"
    End With

End With

Sub setCaption()
    MsgBox Application.caller
End Sub
```

When I try with the above example, I get Type mismatch error.

Comment: What does `MsgBox TypeName(Application.Caller)` give you?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon it gives variant

Comment: Weird, TypeName returns the runtime type, that... *should* be the variant subtype. Does `MsgBox TypeOf Application.Caller Is Object` return true? The idea is to get what type the caller is, IIRC should be a `CommandBarButton`. Alternatively you could take a string parameter and pass it along in the `OnAction` string, that would be more reliable than Application.Caller IMO.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon `MsgBox TypeOf Application.Caller Is Object` gives False

Comment: Where's the type mismatch error being raised exactly?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon At application.caller

Comment: @MathieuGuindon When I pass arg to Sub function, it says macro not found

Comment: Try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25097883/1188513), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25097792/1188513) - remember that string delimiters `"` should be doubled-up inside string literals.

Comment: For a commandbar control `Application.Caller(1)` seems to return the control's index. How about `OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & .Controls(Application.Caller(1).Caption)`